# is there any other way to convert list of images to pdf?

Tags: flutter, pdf

I am trying to convert the list of images to Pdf which is selected from the gallery. I am using [pdf package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to do it but the problem is sometimes it works and sometimes it throws this error

Unhandled Exception: Exception: This widget created more than 100 pages. This may be an issue in the widget or the document. See https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MultiPage-class.html

Even though I am selecting only 2-3 images but nothing seems to work I also tried to change the multipage

```
this.maxPages = 100,
```

I changed 20 to 100 but still facing the same error I searched everything but nothing seems to work this is my code

```
 Future<void> imageToPdfCreater() async {
    try {
      if (compressedFiles.isNotEmpty) {
        pdf.addPage(
          MultiPage(
            build: (Context context) => <pw.Widget>[
              pw.Wrap(
                children: List<pw.Widget>.generate(compressedFiles.length,
                    (int index) {
                  final img = compressedFiles[index];
                  pw.MemoryImage mImg = pw.MemoryImage(img.readAsBytesSync());
                  return pw.Container(
                    child: pw.Column(
                      children: <pw.Widget>[
                        pw.Center(child: pw.Image(mImg)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Need some help on how to make this work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled Exception: Exception: This widget created more than 100 pages.
Mainly, it couses because your widget crosses page limitations. So, we should divide our widgets. First, ,i suggest you to change the first widget as (Listview.builder) and format it.Give your page size to be sure . If, it doesn't work , push your list into a variable and use it into builder like that =>

```
for (GuillotineSystem giyotin in guillotines) {
      giyotinPhotos.add({
        "ustKasaProfiliRef": await getPicture(giyotin.ustKasaProfiliRef),}
then use it like :
pw.Center(
 child: pw.Image(
  height: productSize,
  width: productSize,
pw.MemoryImage(giyotinPhotos[SistemNumarasi]["ustKasaProfiliRef"])),
```

btw,I also suggest you to use Jpeg,Jpg maaaybe if you want hollow background Png. If you may want to see here how i fetch my photos from my API with http library:

```
Future getPicture(var ref2) async {
    var response = await http
et(Uri.parse("https://---YOURAPİ---//Upload/${ref2}_0.jpeg"));
        return response.bodyBytes;
  }
```